# Sybase complains of duplicate insertion where none exists

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have moved some records from my SOURCE table in DB_1 into an ARCHIVE table in another DB_2 (ie. INSERTED the records from SOURCE into ARCHIVE and then DELETED the records from SOURCE.)

My SOURCE table has the following index created as `SOURCE_1`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SOURCE_1
    ON dbo.SOURCE(TRADE_SET_ID, ORDER_ID)
```

The problem is - when I try to insert the rows back into SOURCE from ARCHIVE, Sybase throws the following error:

```
Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'SOURCE' with unique index 'SOURCE_1'
```

And, of course, subsequently fails the insertions.

I confirmed that my SOURCE table does not have these duplicates because the following query returned empty:

```
select * from DB_1.dbo.SOURCE
join DB_2.dbo.ARCHIVE
on DB_1.dbo.SOURCE.TRADE_SET_ID = DB_2.dbo.ARCHIVE.TRADE_SET_ID
AND DB_1.dbo.SOURCE.ORDER_ID = DB_2.dbo.ARCHIVE.ORDER_ID
```

If the above query returned nothing, then that means I haven not violated my unique index constraint on the 2 columns, however Sybase complains that I have.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I really don't see anything wrong (except in your last query your first condition says DB2 instead of DB_2).  You don't have any open transactions or anything, do you?

Comment: One possibility is null.  Null is unique once and would not be found by that query.

Comment: Adam - Ya that was a mistake, but no open transactions.
Blam - I do have NULLs, but I also have NULLs in other tables and don't have problems with the other tables.

Comment: Read my comment.  Null is unique once.  Do you have multiple rows with null in the other tables.

Comment: Blam - actually I just performed a checked, there cannot be NULL in either of those 2 columns and there are no rows with either of those 2 columns being NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sybase is anything like SQL Server in this regard (Which I'm more familiar with), I would suspect that the  index is blocking the insert.  Try disabling the index (along with any other indexes or autoincrement columns) on your archive version before copying over to it, then re-enabling.  Its probable that Sybase would try to automatically create IDs for the insertions, which would interfere with the existing records.

Comment: that is a very interesting proposition Tom. However, if I disable and then enable the index, won't that index have to be rebuilt? The table is a massive table 100M+ rows...I don't think re-creating the index will make my DBA very happy.

Comment: Don't worry about disabling and re-enabling the index on the main table, only on the archive that you are backing up to.  Since it is an archive table, and not likely to be used often, the extra time should be of minimal concern.